# Why does the following file does not exist condition not work in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Don't know why the following rewrite rules do not work. The file-not-exist condition always triggers even though the file article/1.html file does exist. The requested URL is:

https://exampledomain.com/test-a-1.html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)-a-([0123456789_]*)\.html$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/article/%2.html !-f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0123456789_]*)\.html$ news.php?article=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0123456789_]*)\.html$ /article/$2.html
```

If I comment out the !-f RewriteCond it nicely falls through to the second rule and accesses article/1.html. If this condition is active it never rewrites to article/1.html but always goes to news.php?article=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer to my question. There is nothing wrong with my rewrite conditions or rules. They are exactly what they should be. However, `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` does not point to where the Apache documentation says it points to. On my Ionos managed server it points to `/var/www/html`. However, my actual document root is something like `/kunden/homepages/...` So the solution is to use the actual absolute path rather than `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`. Now everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules when .html file is not present in system.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/article/$2.html !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-a-([0-9_]*)\.html/?$ news.php?article=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

##Rules when .html file is present in system.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/article/$2.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-a-([0-9_]*)\.html/?$ article/$2.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: And what is ``%2`` meant to be here?

Comment: And to what capturing pattern does it refer here?

Comment: @arkascha, sorry I am not getting your question here. Please elaborate more.

Comment: `%2` does not contain anything with the code you suggest. You copied something but dropped something else, things don't fit like this. Look at the third line in your code.

Comment: @arkascha, you would have tell me straight forward :) That was code copied from OP, thank you for nice catch; its fixed now, cheers.

Comment: Really? And what is `$2` meant to be here?

Comment: @arkascha, In line `RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-a-([0-9_]*)\.html/?$ news.php?article=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]` $2 is `([0-9_]*)` IMHO.

Comment: And you can use that capture group backwards in the condition? Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha, yes we could use it.

Comment: Thanks for showing an alternative way to approach the rewrite logic. But you are missing that I also want to redirect to news.php when there is a query string even if the HTML file does exist. Essentially I do have a static version of that page. The static version cannot deal with a query string. Thus when there is a query string, or when there is no static version at all, redirect to the dynamic PHP version news.php?article=

Comment: I do like your more compact regular expression [0-9] rather than listing all digits. Thanks for that reminder.